# Clicking on a subsection in the editing help page causes the parent to collapse

Tags: bug

Not sure if this is a known issue, but on the [editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), if you expand a section that has subsections, and then click on the title of one of the subsections, the whole section collapses.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
2. Click on and expand the "Links" section.
3. Click on either "Basic Links" or "Advanced Links"
4. The whole "Links" section collapses.

Comment: @yellowantphil yes I think it happens for any subsection of a collapsible. I just used the "Links" collapsible as an example.

Comment: My first thought was that it's supposed to be a way to get the anchor link so you can share it with someone. But for some reason it's collapsing the whole section.